# How to specify the order that FlashBuilder searches for class definitions

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I have two Flash Builder projects.  Let's call them MainWeb and MainAIR.

MainWeb defines and includes all of the classes for my application including a runtime loaded module that interfaces with our web services.  MainAIR's Source Path references MainWeb/src and includes only two unique parts.  The first file is of course the root MXML document.  The other file overrides a compiled, runtime module defined in MainWeb called DataStreamer.  DataStreamer interfaces with our web services for MainWeb and the alternate version of DataStreamer interfaces with the OS filesystem for MainAIR. This makes a very easy to maintain pair of projects and easy to build both the web version and the AIR version of my application.

It has worked well until I needed to add an instance of mx.controls.Image.  Image references SWFLoader and loads resource/content swfs at runtime.  Some of those resources have executable code, so I needed to do the following:

```
loaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;
```

This works well from MainAIR, but raises an error in MainWeb because of course allowLoadBytesCodeExecution is only available to AIR projects.  So, I thought I could use the same technique I used with the runtime module and just define a new version of the class in MainAIR.  This failed.  FlashBuilder is compiling in MainWeb's version of the class or Flash Player is instantiating MainWeb's version.  I can't tell without decompiling the code.

How can I specify the order, which FlashBuilder should search for class definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting solution.  Add another Source Path item to the list for MainAIR, and then move MainWeb/src item below the new one.  For example, setting the Source Path list of MainAIR to the following resolved the problem:

```
MainWeb/assets
MainWeb/src
```